# Identity Server with Angular Client App

Tags: angular, identityserver4

I have set up an Identity Server 4 that is deployed on, say, 192.168.1.50 and port 5000. I have Angular 5 client app that is deployed on, say 192.168.1.60 and port 4200.

I have provided the following as client settings in the Angular app.

```
return {
    authority: 'http://192.168.1.50:5000/',
    client_id: 'client_app',
    redirect_uri: 'http://192.168.1.60:4200/auth-callback',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://192.168.1.60:4200/',
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope: 'openid profile api1, api2',
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    silent_redirect_uri: 'http://192.168.1.60:4200/silent-refresh.html'
  };
```

I have provided the following configuration in the Identity Server,

```
new Client {
     ClientId = "client_app",
     ClientName = "client_app_name",
     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
     AllowedScopes =  {
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
          "api1",
          "api2",
     },
     RedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://192.168.1.60:4200/auth-callback" },
     PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://192.168.1.60:4200" },
     AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> { "http://192.168.1.60:4200" },
     AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
     RequireConsent = false
}
```

The above gives me an error:

```
unauthorized_client Invalid redirect_uri
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I correct in assuming that the URL for the redirect URL should typically be a path in the client application. Most of the examples have redirect_uri as localhost.

Any help in this direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to add your silent_redirect_uri to the RedirectUris collection too.

Comment: Also, beware of the slash at the end of redirect URLs - what you send as a redirect URL, needs to match exactly as saved in the client settings.

Comment: Check the identity server logs it will tell you exactly what you are sending as well as what redirect uris are allowed its easier to diagnose the issue.  @SašaĆetković the / is at the end of the logout redirect uri which isnt the same error hes getting.